# Set Extension For Handler.ashx

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0, ashx, generic-handler

I have a generic handler `Image.ashx` that crops/resizes images on the fly by reading information from the querystring like `Image.ashx?filename=foo.jpg&maxwidth=200&maxheight=300`.

Is there a way that I can change the extension of this handler to `.jpg`? (it always returns jpgs) I'd rather the calls look like this: `Image.JPG?filename=foo.jpg&maxwidth=200&maxheight=300`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [routing infrastructure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) to point image.jpg to image.ashx